# Insert SQL Entries sorted

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I have a very large sql table that I want to display. However, ist most cases I just want to have it sorted by my datetime-column.

Unfortunately, the regular select-query only displays the table ordered by the primary key (id) - therefore, I have to always manually add 'order by' to my select-query, which is a problem, because sorting the table takes several seconds, even with index.

So my question, is there a way to insert new entries *sorted* into the table? (by 'sorted', I mean, sorted by the datetime-column, instead of the id column). The incoming entry (id=50) should be sorted before id=49, because it has an earlier datetime-value

Then, using a `SELECT * FROM myTable` should already show everything sorted by datetime

I realize that it's a bad practice and that I should use order-by, but its not really feasible in my case, because I have millions of entries, which have to be sorted again and again for every select

Comment: how do I do that? when I use a reuglar 'insert' it just uses the primary key (id) and auto increments it and adds it to the bottom of the table. How do I insert it correctly?

Comment: right now, I just use regular `INSERT` to insert, and `SELECT...ORDER BY' to display, which takes too long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a MyISAM table, you can do

```
ALTER TABLE your_table ORDER BY whatever_column;
```

But the table does not stay this way, when you insert or update entries.

Read more about it [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html).

This does not make sense for InnoDB tables, however. They are sorted by the clustered index. In this case an option can be to extend your primary key to `(datetime_column, column_thats_primary_key_so_far)`. This is untested, personally I would add an `ORDER BY` to the `SELECT`, just in case.

Comment: Thank you, this was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It won't keep the data sorted for future inserts, but you can change the table ordering like this:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ORDER BY timestamp
```